# Copy record with new ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 Databases in same server. DB1 have table called E1, and DB2 have table called E1.

E1

ID  Name

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

E2

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   C
3   D
```

I would like to copy names that in table E1 and not exist in table E2 with new "ID".
So E2 will be

E2

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   C
3   D
4   B
```

---

My query is :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TEST_DB].[dbo].[E1] ON 
INSERT INTO [TEST_DB].[dbo].[E1](ID,Name) 
  SELECT ID,Name FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[E1]AS a 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
  SELECT a.ID , a.Name FROM [TEST_DB].[dbo].[E1] AS b WHERE a.ID = b.ID and a.Name = b.Name ) 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TEST_DB].[dbo].[E1] off
```

Comment: does it the ID column auto increment ?

Comment: Yes it is auto increment.

Comment: you just need to select THE Name without ID

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into e2 (name)
    select name from e1
    where name not in (select name from e2
                       where name is not null)
```

Assuming id is an auto-increment column.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into e2 (id, name)
values ((select max(id) from e2)+1, (select name from e1 where name not in (select name from e2)
```

with id auto-increment.

Comment: What if there is not data in e2?

Comment: What about it? Then it will give an error and nothing will be done.

Comment: And do you think the OP wants a query that can give errors? You shouldn't post an answer that can throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can just join tables and check what you don't have in E2 from E1 and insert only those ... As you said that ID is auto increment ... just select what you need using *LEFT JOIN*

```
if object_ID('tempdb..#E1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #E1
create table #E1 (Name nvarchar(10))
insert into #E1 (Name) values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')

if object_ID('tempdb..#E2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #E2
create table #E2 (Name nvarchar(10))
insert into #E2 (Name) values ('A'), ('C'), ('D')

Select * from #E2

Insert into #E2 (Name)
Select e1.Name from #E1 e1
LEFT JOIN #E2 e2 on e1.Name = e2.Name
where e2.Name IS NULL

Select * from #E2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[E2] (Name)
SELECT A.Name FROM [dbo].[E1] A 
WHERE A.Name NOT IN ( SELECT B.Name FROM [dbo].[E2] B)
```